# C program working half when you run it from cmd file

Tags: c, input, exe

I was coding a C program that gives us the area of sphere and circle. You put inputs and than it calculates. But there is a problem. I have done this project for pi day and I must send it to someone.
When I open the program from exe file it can only go for circle and spehere's radius input part. When you input something, it closes itself. When I run it from Dev C++ there isn't any problem. What is wrong with exe file?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #define PI 3.14159265
    
    /* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
    
    int main() {
        getch();
        char bilgi;
        printf("Kurenin hacmini mi yoksa dairenin alanini mi hesaplamak istersiniz?\n");
        printf("Daire icin girdi kismina d, kure icin k yaziniz:");
        scanf("%c", &bilgi);
            if(bilgi == 'k') {
                    float yaricap;
        float hacim;
        printf("Merhaba, bu fonksiyon kure hacmini hesaplamak icin tasarlanmistir.\n");
        printf("Lutfen kurenin yaricapini giriniz:");
        scanf("%f", &yaricap);
        hacim = (4.00*3.00)*PI*(yaricap*yaricap*yaricap);
        printf("Kurenin hacmi %f", hacim);
                return 0;
    
            } else if(bilgi == 'd'){
        getch();     
        float yaricapdaire;
        float alan;
        printf("Bu fonksiyon dairenin alanini hesaplamak icin tasarlanmistir.\n");
        printf("Lutfen dairenin yaricapini giriniz:");
        scanf("%f", &yaricapdaire);
        alan = PI*(yaricapdaire*yaricapdaire);
        printf("Dairenin alani %f", alan);
                
            return 0;       
                
            }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *When you input something, it closes itself* - you mean the *console window* is closing itself? This is what console programs do. They terminate and the window is closing if the program is not telling it to wait.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window by hand to run the program.

Comment: You can have the program wait for input at the end before exiting.

Comment: Yes it terminates itself suddenly. It should give us a result beforme terminating itself.

Comment: @Barmar can you define it little better for me. I am pretty new in C programming.

Comment: It gives you the result. You just can't see it as the window is closing. Just run `cmd`, then navigate to your `exe` and run it from there

Comment: @EugeneSh. so is there anyway to pause it before closing?

Comment: Oh thank you but my teacher may not do it? Is there any easy way?

Comment: Add `getchar();` in the end. Your teacher should know this stuff though

Comment: At the end put `printf("Press Return to exit"); getchar();`

Comment: Your teacher should know how to run programs so they can see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Putting a `getch();` before every `return 0;`
fixed it.